# Get screen sizes & set them in carousel view android

Tags: android, carousel

Here you can see my carousel layout xml file.

```
 <com.touchmenotapps.carousel.simple.HorizontalCarouselLayout
        android:id="@+id/carousel_layout_event"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/carousel_layout" >

    </com.touchmenotapps.carousel.simple.HorizontalCarouselLayout>
```

I want to set the running android simulator screen width & height to the android:layout_width & android:layout_height...

can anyone help me. thanks

Comment: What's wrong in having `match_parent`s for `layout_width` and `layout_height`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HorizontalCarouselLayout hcl=(HorizontalCarouselLayout)findViewById(R.id.carousel_layout_event);

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

hcl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width,height));
```

Comment: here I can't give the command "display.getSize(size)". because getsize(size) method is undefined in Display class. Is there any way to overcome this problem.....

Comment: yes there are other methods for API level below 13, try this
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth(); 
int height = display.getHeight();
these method are actually deprecated after API Level 13, so if you want to make project that is API Level 13+ use the previous getSize();

Answer (score 0):

Firs you get the divice size i.e.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int divWidth= size.x;
int divHeight = size.y;
```

Create a function to set the layout params. i.e.

```
public void setWidthHeight(View v, int width, int height){
    LayoutParams lp;
    lp = v.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = width;
    lp.height = height;
    v.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

then call this function as,

```
setWidthHeight(yourView,divWidth,divHeight);
```